# c++ program to solve a problem

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am  stuck with a c++ program which is an assignment.
 Please help me out.
Please suggest  an approach if possible,
 *thanks in advance*

Problem:

Given two vessels, one of which can accommodate **a** liters of water and the other which can 
accommodate **b** liters of water, determine the number of steps required to obtain exactly  **c**
liters of water in one of the vessels.

At the beginning both vessels are empty. The following operations are counted as 'steps':

- emptying a vessel,
- filling a vessel,
- pouring water from one vessel to the other, without spilling, until one of the vessels is 
  either full or empty.

Input

An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of test cases, followed by t sets of input data, 
each consisting of three positive integers **a** (the number of liters the first container can hold), 
**b** (the number of liters the second container can hold), and **c** (the final amount of liters of 
water one vessel should contain), not larger than 40000, given in separate lines.

Comment: you dont know how to solve this problem or writing code in C++?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far and where you are stuck. (This problem seems to be incomplete; you can only get `c` litres of water if `c` is a multiple of the highest common factor of `a` and `b`.)

Comment: the die-hard3 problem, classics! watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfQxZTtbCTg for clues

Comment: @Hammerite: you can do difference of `a` and `b`. In fact, this is a classic puzzle (http://www.shvoong.com/exact-sciences/mathematics/1697283-die-hard-gallons-puzzle/). It was used in the "Die Hard 3" movie.

Comment: @Sylvain Defresne: Yes, it is true that you can make the difference of `a` and `b`, because the difference between `a` and `b` is a multiple of the highest common factor of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a nice simple maths homework.

My advice, ignore any coding aspect for now, and concentrate on how you as a human would work it out given the two vessels in your hands.

You have 3 variables, the capacities of your vessels.
x and y in this would be the quantities you need of a and b to work. Given at the time in question a, b and c will be replaced with numers.

In short, ax+by=c

So, if c is 12, and a is 2 and b is 3.

you have 
2x+3b=12

now you have a simple equation

Given you know you want say 12 litres, work out in your head, how you would work it out if you were doing it yourself.

It sounds like you're asking for homework though.

Comment: "So, if c is 12, and a is 2 and b is 3."  
Putting 12 liters of liquid into a 3 liters vessel will be a real challenge.

Comment: I know, but it also you have to accept you may not have the vessels to do it accurately :) However, I read it as c was the destination and you fill it using a and b, but the principal remains the same